# Got 422 Unprocessable Entity After Ran CURL Command To Create New Place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, curl

I had a little problem which is my create new place didn't go through.

Here is my curl command :

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"place": {"name": "the stroke", "address": "the stroke YOLO", "description":"YOLOOOOO", "phone":"9128911", "website":"www.thestrokes.com"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/places
-i -H 'Authorization: Token token="8f8315d4892044479450ef3403c0af95"'
```

And this my place controller gist :

```
 module Api 
    module V1
        class PlacesController < Api::ApiController  # Api::BaseController
            respond_to :json
         before_action :authenticate #This authenticate method inherit from Api Controller
         skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token


         def index
            respond_with @user.places
         end

         def show
            respond_with Place.find(params[:id])
         end

         def create
            respond_with Place.create(params[:product])
         end

         def update
            respond_with Place.update(params[:id], params[:products])
         end

         def destroy
            respond_with Place.destroy(params[:id])
         end

            # private

            # def authenticate
            #   authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
            #   current_user.find_by(access_token: token)
            # end

            # end
        end
    end
end
```

and here is my log:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/places" for ::1 at 2015-07-31 17:07:10 +0800
Processing by Api::V1::PlacesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"place"=>{"name"=>"the stroke", "address"=>"the stroke YOLO", "description"=>"YOLOOOOO", "phone"=>"9128911", "website"=>"www.thestrokes.com"}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."access_token" = ? LIMIT 1  [["access_token", "8f8315d4892044479450ef3403c0af95"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 6ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Hope someone can help me with this question.